# Is there in Tapestry common property to convert null string from server-side to empty string on client-side?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, components, textfield, tapestry

I am newbie for Tapestry5. I have found that null string value from server-side in textfield produces NullPointerException. The option to change null value string to empty string and vice versa on server-side (when saving in DB) doesn't look acceptable. Does it mean that that I must create new translator for null value strings please? Or there exists some configuration property?

Comment: What's wrong with doing it on the server-side exactly? it's just `var == null ? "" : var`

Comment: It's not quite clear to me when the NullPointerException (NPE) occurs for you. Rendering a textfield with its value parameter bound to `null` does _not_ cause an NPE to be thrown. Likewise, unless you tweak Tapestry's default translators, an empty textfield arrives as `null` without a problem, i.e. an NPE thrown. So, I'm guessing, the NPE is thrown further down the road in your code, probably in your persistence layer, anyway not within Tapestry.